# haml select_tag with constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, html-select

I'm new to Ruby and Haml, so I"m going around in circles on this. Googling isn't giving me any sample code I can use.

I can use the `select_tag` and populate the list from a table. But I can't figure out how to use a simple static list of items. Can someone change this to be proper Haml? Note: the source table is 'email' and the field is 'status'.

```
= select_tag(:email, :status, {"canceled", "pending", "success"})
```

I'm looking to get a dropdown list that just has the items "canceled, pending, success" in it.

The error I get is `odd number list for Hash._hamlout.format_script...`

Update: I found some sample code that seemed to be what I need, and it doesn't give any errors, but the dropdown box is empty:

```
= select_tag(:email, :status,{ "canceled" => "1", "pending" => "2", "success"=>"3"})
```

Here is the HTML it produces:

```html
<select female="2" male="1" id="email" name="email">status </select >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the tag helper rather than the object-oriented helper. Use `select`

I'd also recommend using `options_for_select`. Like so:

```
= select(:email, :status, options_for_select([["canceled", "1"], ["pending", "2"], ["success", "3"]]))
```

See:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Answer (score 1):

Got it working! I need to use "Select" instead of "Select_tag".  :-)

= select(:email, :status,{ "canceled" => "canceled", "pending" => "pending", "success"=>"success"})